# Como faço para subtrair valores de uma lista adicionados por input em python

Tags: python-3.x

estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
subtração = list()
    su = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))
    subtração.append(su)
    while True:
                resposta = str(input('Deseja continuar? [S/N]')).upper()[0]
                if resposta in 'SN':
                    break
                print ('erro')
            if resposta == 'N':
                break
    sub = 0
    for s in subtração:
      sub -= s
    print(sub)
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá, sua dúvida não está clara. Tente descrever melhor a sua pergunta.

Se você quer remover um valor de uma lista `lista = [5,8,3]` você pode usar a função `.pop()`
Se você quer percorrer uma lista e subtrair um valor da lista seria

```
lista = [5,8,3]
num = 3
print(lista)
lista = [x-num for x in lista] 
print (lista)
```

Não se esqueça de estudar o básico em python. Não é pythonico iniciar uma lista chamando a função `list()`